# Sorting with a custom order schema in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have many rows in a MySQL table with a reference represented by a number between `0` and `10000`.

I'd like to sort my rows by this reference in a custom order, like this one :

1. All the rows with a reference between `2000` and `2999`
2. Then all the rows with a reference between `4000` and `4999`
3. Then all the rows with a reference between `3000` and `3999`
4. Then all the rows with a reference between `1000` and `1999`

Is it possible to do something like this with only one MySQL query?

Comment: Share your effort and desired output or sample data .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional ordering, like :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM mytable t
ORDER BY
    CASE 
        WHEN t.num BETWEEN 2000 AND 2999 THEN 1
        WHEN t.num BETWEEN 4000 AND 4999 THEN 2
        WHEN t.num BETWEEN 3000 AND 3999 THEN 3
        WHEN t.num BETWEEN 1000 AND 1999 THEN 4
    END,
    t.num
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `order by` with `case`:

```
order by
case 
  when reference between 2000 and 2999 then 0
  when reference between 4000 and 4999 then 1
  when reference between 3000 and 3999 then 2
  when reference between 1000 and 1999 then 3
  else 4
end
```

you can have additional ordering with other columns too.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below - using define a custom order by CASE WHEN Expression

```
select * from tablename
order by 
case when reference>=2000 and reference<=2999 then 1
     when reference>=4000 and reference<=4999 then 2
     when reference>=3000 and reference<=3999 then 3
     when reference>=1000 and reference<=1999 then 4 end
```